# sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

i run the script by using `./myshfile.sh actors`

```
sed -n -e "1,$1p" test.txt > test2.txt && mv test2.txt test.txt
```

produces the following error and i can't find why...

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected `,'
```

tried to use single quotes

```
sed -n -e '1,$1p' test.txt > test2.txt && mv test2.txt test.txt
```

but that produces another error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `1'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `"1,$1p"`, the `$1` is expanded by the shell, and `sed` sees `1,actorsp`. `actorsp` isn't a valid sed address, so it gives an error. The error text looks a bit weird to me though, it seems to recognize `a` as a command and then go back to wondering about the comma.

In `'1,$1p'`, the `$1` is *not* expanded by the shell, and `sed` sees `1,$1p`. `$` is a valid address, it's used to mark the last line, so `1,$` simply means "all lines". `1` isn't a valid command though, so an error it is.

You didn't state what you meant to do, so it's hard to help there.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using the separator,

```
sed -n -e "1,/$1/p" test.txt
```

the code u tried will expand as,

```
sed -n -e 1,actorsp test.txt
```

in which sed will take option `p` as a part of regex `actorp`.So use delimiter between regex and option to make it work.

Comment: In `1,actorsp`, the `actorsp` part is not taken as a regular expression at all. The error message indicates that `sed` doesn't identify it as a line number, nor as a regular expression (and it therefore does not know why there's a comma in front of it).